Are there any poisonous species of salvia?
My father used to have salvia growing in his garden with green leaves and purple flowers
Are there any species of salvia that are poisonous?
¿Can salvia always be used in cooking, or only sometimes used in cooking?

Without further research, S. divinorum comes to mind.
A plant that’s used for its hallucinogenic effects should never be used carelessly in regular cooking. It may not be poisonous in the literal sense, but it’s also certainly not safe.

Note: if such sage is sold, it will clearly marked (because it would be used for the hallucinogenics properties), and probably not cheap. Do not take plants from random places (botanical parks, gardens) unless you know what it is (and possibly also having permission)
